# Why has the phone number in description metatags stopped being clickable?

Tags: meta-description

The description meta tags in the source code containing a phone number USED TO cause that phone number to become clickable and callable by any native mobile phone dialer INSTANTLY -  from any search engine search results page when searching on a mobile phone.

THIS IS SUDDENLY NO LONGER WORKING.

That description meta tag phone number automatic link to mobile phone dialers is not there anymore.

The only scenario where it is still working today is this combination: Iphone + Safari + Yahoo Search.

[image]

All other combinations of mobile phone kinds, mobile phone browsers and mobile search engines  - do not work ANYMORE as they used to automatically.

Does anyone know what happened and when?

I noticed this a week ago. Can't find anything on the web about this sudden unexpected change - which damages a lot of service oriented businesses by forcing users who are only interested in the phone number..and not in navigating to the business page - forces them to go to the website and look for the number there  instead of just calling right away from the search engine results page without ever seeing the actual business website. This sudden loss of this capability...makes the user experience more difficult and may result in less phone calls and consequently loss of business.

How can this be remedied?

Comment: Are you sure that it wasn't a browser plugin that was making those clickable?   There are plugins such as [Telify for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/telify/) that will do that.   Maybe you are using a different browser, or cleaned up your extensions.

Comment: No....it was automatic as default and quite a common feature.And everybody was praising it. No plug in involved.

Comment: Here:

http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/iphone-search-result-optimization-tip-1-phone-numbers-in-meta-tags.html

Comment: I am only interested in it working on MOBILE PHONES not on desktops. And it worked on all mobile phones since always. It stopped working recently. Does anyone, you, know when and why?

Comment: The whole greatness of this feature was that it worked as default...no plug -ins required on the site of user's browser on their phones. And now it DOES NOT work. Bummer!

Comment: "BENEFITS: While this was not necessarily a revolutionary find for all businesses, it had some powerful implications for:

a. local businesses (often people will just look for the phone number of a business)
b. emergency services (eg. tow trucks, plumbers)
c. impulse or on-demand purchases (eg. pizza, taxis)

Sure, it did not help sites rank better, but it has had definitely increased the number of phone calls received for certain types of businesses."

Well....NOT ANYMORE :(

Comment: BTW: I searched the web for anyone mentioning this sudden CHANGE - and it looks like NOBODY noticed. Am I the only one?

Comment: Someone else did notice this ... there is a comment (posted yesterday by Kwa czorek) at the bottom of this page: http://www.smekdigital.com/add-clickable-phone-numbers-in-your-google-serps/

Comment: Thank you...but no answer there either :)

Comment: This seems to be at the client end - the phone/browser - as opposed to any SERP feature returned by a search engine or anything that has to do with the page itself short of a neat and handy trick with the meta-tag. Interesting question. Possible software updates? Who knows? Cheers!!

Comment: We are lucky to have pulled out an old .....gallaxy s4 with service on it.......with no updates to browsers ....and same thing....phone number in metatag not working as clickable/dialable number ....old phone with old browser....so our IT guy speculated only ...theory so far... that it must be the SERVICE PROVIDERS that removed that functionality for some reason. We are still researching and testing.

Comment: So....it does not look like a  client...phone...browser....predicament.

Comment: Your phone number was clickable in the Knowledge Panel (business info on the right-side) in desktop, and in mobile browsers I tested. You could use browser screenshot services to confirm. Newer browsers should convert phone numbers in a recognizable format to clickable links, older ones may not. Browser extensions like Skype and Google Voice also will make phone numbers in content (including SERP) clickable, and specific browsers like Chrome may as well without them. Be sure to use the `tel:` schema in your content:  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/

Comment: 1. Thank you Dan. However this is not the issue here. Sure...a specially placed phone number...those places you mentioned...will be clickable in both desktop and mobile browsers. And of course on the website itself a tel: or  a href call links are working right now...some applied to images or text.  That is working. As you said it should. This case is about MOBILE PHONES USERS ONLY. Not desktop users. Additionally this case is specifically about a telephone number placed specifically at the beginning of the description meta tag in the source code of the multiple pages of the site.

Comment: 2. This used to cause this number to be instantly recognizable by the native mobile phone dialers and be visible as a blue link ON GOOGLE or YAHOO SEARCH RESULTS PAGES specifically .....making it possible for the user to clIck that number in the description under the link to the page...and call...WITHOUT EVER HAVING TO ACTUALLY SURF TO THAT PAGE ITSELF.

Comment: 3.. The case here is that this is no longer working. The only scenario this is still working in, is this combination: IPHONE + SAFARI + YAHOO SEARCH. I hope I clarified this predicament. Many users use search engines to find just the phone number to call. They are not interested in going to that business page itself. Something happened...and now they have to either go to the page and look for the number there or copy the number from the description and oaste it to their phone dialer. This is the problem here and I would like this to work as described above - again.

Comment: I have edited my original question and made it specific to  mobile phones...to clarify the precise nature of this issue.

Comment: @Voitek You did see that I wrote that I tested it with mobile browsers too, right? As you noted, there are no reports regarding this, and users here aren't seeing it either. So what would you like us to do about it, "fix" Google? If indeed they changed something (which nobody here or or elsewhere seems to be seeing), we don't have any control over that, nor would we be able to answer _why_. They do make changes from time-to-time, and the best we can do as users is to adapt to them, when indeed they occur.

Comment: Questions here are required to be about [web sites under your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and since this has turned into an [open-ended discussion](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on something we have no control over and can't verify, it's really best if you report this as an issue on Google's Product Forum for Google Search here:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/websearch

Comment: Dan...I appreciate your time you have spent doing the research. As I pointed out the issue here is a phone number in description meta tag...not anywhere else. This used to work as default before. My question is to someone who knows what happened. Apparently nobody knows. I will keep experimenting.

Comment: Here is a link from years ago proving that it INDEED used to work and the benefits of it.

http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/iphone-search-result-optimization-tip-1-phone-numbers-in-meta-tags.html

And it does not work anymore.

Thank you kindly for your efforts. I am hoping that somebody will find out what happened and maybe this could be reversed as it hurts businesses by removing this capability - whatever happened. I will experiment and research and if I find a solution I will let you know.

Comment: The question has been edited as per "on hold" instructions by Dan.

Comment: That's a pretty old article (2008) and specific to iPhones. As you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) `In Safari on iOS, telephone number detection is on by default`. Browsers control that, not Google. They would have had to specifically convert phone numbers into clickable links using `<a href="tel://+15555551212">+1 (555) 555-1212</a>` or JavaScript. However they didn't use either inside of SERP descriptions, that was your _browser_ that was converting it to a clickable link.

Comment: When I search for your site using Google Search on mobile browsers, your phone number appears as clickable in the Knowledge Panel along with your business info using JavaScript. That should work on most modern mobile browsers. In short, Google didn't change anything in regards to displaying descriptions in SERP. If it did, you'd see _countless_ references to that on the net.

Comment: So Dan, what has happened that it stopped working as default - as it worked 8 years ago and on until recently?

RE:" As you can see here In Safari on iOS, telephone number detection is on by default"

Yes, I knew that. Just like I wrote at the beginning and even provided a screen shot. 

So, does anyone know why it stopped working EVERYWHERE else, except the Iphone,Safari, Yahoo" scenario?

Comment: Anyway, Dan, Thank you for your time, but you have not told me anything that I haven't known already....as my question and comments in English state here clearly. 

So I will repeat the question for the last time and leave you guys alone: Does ANYONE know what happened and why? Saying that nobody else noticed and there is no uproar is not an answer. That just shows that most were not even aware of that great feature that is NO MORE :) Which does not surprise me at all :) Ta, ta!